# Geographical Regions Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

What template should we follow for the the wiki summary of geographical-related tags?

e.g. [us](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) [canada](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada) [europe](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) [new-england](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-england) [new-zealand](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-zealand) [alps](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alps)

Should we follow a format like the following:

> Geographical Region: Canada, Country.

Comment: Hmmm - maybe this question would have been better asked **before** you started with the tagging :-) Jokes aside, I think this reads okay.

Comment: Hehe, ya. I figured I would ask before submitting 20 tags update. ;-) most of them have no description as of today.